# View generating error message: String was not recognized as a valid Boolean

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, viewmodel

Within an admin page I originally was generating several checkboxes within a view as per below:

Model:

```
public class Foo
{
    public const string Bar = "SomeString";
}
```

View:

```
@Html.CheckBox(Foo.Bar)
@Html.Label(Foo.Bar)
```

However, I wanted to change the display name of several of the checkboxes, so I created a view model (to later add a display name attribute):

```
public class FooViewModel
{
     public string Bar
     {
         get { return Foo.Bar; }
     }
}
```

And modified the view:

```
@Html.CheckBox(Model.Bar)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Bar)
```

However, the view is now generating an error when rendering the checkbox:

> String was not recognized as a valid Boolean

Note, that if I change the property name within the view model to anything other than "Bar"  the view is rendered correct. EG:

```
public class FooViewModel
{
     public string WTF
     {
         get { return Foo.Bar; }
     }
}

@Html.CheckBox(Model.WTF)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.WTF)
```

Can anybody explain to me why this error is occurring if my viewmodel property is named "Bar"?

**Edit**:
I have updated my question slightly seeing as how, i'm generating some confusion. The view is used as a search form and the checkboxes are simply used for selecting "search critera".

I'm generating the checkbox in this fashion so the name / id of the checkbox is related to corresponding business logic within the controller.

I'm aware that code will not compile if property name / field name within the same class are identical. That is not the issue, as i'm simply initializing a property from constant within a different namespace.

Comment: @ChrisF No, that parameter would be a string: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460245.aspx

Comment: @Shark - ah thanks - it's been a while since I did this stuff. Comment deleted.

Comment: Are you referencing the property as though it is a `static` one?  How did that even compile?

Comment: @Shark yes, that is correct. Everything works / compiles correctly as long as the property name of the 'view model' is different than that of the backing constant string from the base model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a different checkbox constructor resolves the issue:

```
@Html.CheckBox(Model.Bar, false)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Bar)
```

Comment: i still don't get what your trying to do. CheckBox needs to bind to a `bool`, not a string. You should be doing `@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.SomeBooleanProperty)`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a constant called `Bar` and a property called `Bar`:

```
public class Foo
{
    public const string Bar = "SomeString";

    public string Bar
    {
        get { return Foo.Bar; }
    }
}
```

This particular code snippet is invalid C# and won't even compile.

This being said the `CheckBox/CheckBoxFor` helpers in ASP.NET MVC work with boolean values. So I really don't understand why are you even attempting to bind it to a string property and the purpose of this `Bar` string constant.

The correct would be to have the following view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "som estring")]
    public bool MyBoolValue { get; set; }
}
```

and in the strongly typed view:

```
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.MyBoolValue)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.MyBoolValue)
```

Comment: Thanks Darin, I have updated my question slightly to avoid the confusion I was causing. The property is simply being initialized from a constant value from a class in a different namespace. They are not in the same class as per your example.